# Applying a property to all the labels in the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this table `<table></table>` and there are many `<label></label>`'s inside. Is there a way to apply some property to all the labels inside the table but to none of the labels outside.

In other words, I'd like to write something:

```
FOR each label IN my table:
    APPLY: property
```

PS: I know about the classes, but if I use class, I'll have to use `<class= >` for each label manually.

Comment: You can add a class/id to table and then you can refer labels within that class/id to apply properties.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m9qb0gof/ like this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to style `<label>`'s that are inside a `table`? If so, just use a parent/child selector so only those applicable are styled as follows:

```css
table label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>LABEL INSIDE TABLE</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

<label>LABREL OUTSIDE TABLE</label>
```

If you add a class to the appropritate table's, you can style labels only in those tables:

```css
table.test label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="test">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>LABEL INSIDE TABLE with class TEST</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label>LABEL INSIDE TABLE with no class</label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>

<label>LABREL OUTSIDE TABLE</label>
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I have more than 1 table and I need to apply the attribute to one table's labels, but not to the others.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is google more and read more.

it called css selector. you can use it like this

> ```
> table label{
>  color:red;
>  background:green;
> }
> ```

and so on. the class it self it's to specify what this particular label should do and this label should do. you can find it more in here [all about selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)